# AWS Athena: How can we get integer value as string with thousand comma separator in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

How can we show integer numbers with thousand comma separator.

So, by executing the below statement

`select * from 1234567890`

How can we get the result as `1,234,567,890`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by casting number to string and using regex:

```
with dataset(num) as (
    values (1234567890),
    (123456789),
    (12345678),
    (1234567),
    (123456),
    (12345),
    (1234),
    (123)
)

select regexp_replace(cast(num as VARCHAR), '(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))', '$1,')
from dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 1,234,567,890 |
| 123,456,789 |
| 12,345,678 |
| 1,234,567 |
| 123,456 |
| 12,345 |
| 1,234 |
| 123 |